# gdb on iphone device not stopping at breakpoints

Tags: iphone, gdb, reverse-engineering, jailbreak

I am debugging and iPhone app without a symbol table. The device is jailbroken and I am attaching gdb locally on the device by passing the pid (starting the app in gdb doesn't seem to work on iOS 5). None of the breakpoints I set are getting triggered. I set the breakpoints at offsets I have from a class-dump, but I presume they are not getting hit because of ASLR in iOS 5.

I tried removing the MH_PIE flag using the script from here http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/build/mac/change_mach_o_flags.py?view=markup and otool shows that was done correctly. However, after the change the application no longer launches.

Am I setting the breakpoints wrong or is this because of ASLR? If it's the randomization then how do I effectively disable it on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're looking to do is debug the app with GDB, then disabling ASLR via the MH_PIE flag is just fine.  Since that program patches the binary, you will need to resign the app.  Using a program called `ldid` (from the package called "Link Identity Editor" in Cydia), you can pseudo-codesign the app.

```
root# cd /var/mobile/Applications/*/Example.app/
root# mach_flags --no-pie Example
root# ldid -s Example
root# gdb
(gdb) attach -waitfor Example
```

Then just tap the app's icon. The app will appear to hang. From this point, go back to GDB and it should be loaded. Now, just set your breakpoints with `b *0x<address>` and you can ignore ASLR altogether as it is disabled.

Answer (score -1):

I've just gotten stuck with this as well. There's no easy fix that I can find, the best workaround I've found so far is to use include assert.h and use it throughout.

Update:

You're right. I was thinking in the case of having one's own source. However, gdb on iOS jail broken devices has this known issue of not hitting breakpoints. I have discussed the matter with those who originally brought gdb to Cydia, and they have recommended I attempt to work out the issue myself. Without any free time for that, I have given up for now.

This is a warning to anyone trying to debug via gdb on jail broken iOS, to either look into the issue yourself or give up. It should not be expected to work, and using asserts is the next best thing, if you are working on your own source and not attempting to reverse engineer someone else's app.

I was not trying to answer the question at hand and so I do indeed deserve the downvote. But the information should get out there regardless.

Comment: He doesn't have the source of the application, so how would he include assert.h? This doesn't answer the question.